# keymap (overlay / text property): how to create and modify?

Tags: keymap, highlighting, text-properties, overlays

I'd like to have certain keymap active when the cursor is in a particular highlighted area. For instance, I would like to bind `hl-todo-next` to some easy key combination, but only when the cursor is on such a TODO item, as marked by `ht-todo-mode`.

I understand that a piece of text or an overlay can have its own `keymap` property which would work that way.

How do I best augment keymaps for highlighting already put by *existing* modes, such as `hl-todo-mode` or `highlight-symbol-mode`? Can I e.g. associate it with a particular named face?

Specifically, what would be a good way to:

- Add / update a keymap for a particular already highlighted fragment of text on which the cursor is currently positioned?
- Remove / restore that keymap when the highlighting vanishes (because of the cursor movement or the text being changed).

I definitely can just run a hook at every cursor movement, or character typed, or time elapsed; I wonder if there are nicer ways to do that, and are there any subtleties not immediately obvious from the elisp documentation.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot associate a keymap to a face, but you can associate a keymap to text as a text property or to an overlay. You need to create the keymap and assign it as the value of the `keymap` text property of the text in question or of the overlay.

Comment: Your last paragraph expresses the question. Scan the buffer, looking for the text highlighted by those modes, and put property `keymap` on that highlighted text (or the overlay, if the highlighting is by overlay). Or if you know which overlays are used, give them the `keymap` property you want. Or advise the functions that do the highlighting, to make them also add property `keymap`.

Comment: @Drew: Thanks! I just thought that maybe there are already some existing tools that do a similar thing. How do I advise? E.g. when `highlight-symbol-mode` is on, symbols get highlighted dynamically; how do I best update the keymap for the symbol under cursor when it happens? And how do I best remove the keymap when the highlight is gone?

Comment: Please pose specific separate questions for your follow-up questions. Comments can be deleted at any time. Each question should be specific, which solicits pertinent, specific answers. Thx.

Comment: @Drew: I hope I have made my question more specific.